# Exclude a particular type from a return type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let suppose I want to exclude some type of a method that returns a "wide" type.

Something that would look like that but doesn't work :

```
type FooFn = {
    <T extends Record<string, any>>(): T extends Promise<any> ? never : T;
};

const foo: FooFn = () => ({ 'ok': 'ok' }); // should work
const foo2: FooFn = () => { return Promise.resolve({ 'ok': 'ok' }) }; // should fail
```

Edit:
What I'm looking for is part of a wider problem.

```
type Fn = () => Record<string, any>; // should not allow Promises, Observables etc. 
type AsyncFn = () => Promise<Record<string, any>>;

const foo: Fn = () => ({ 'ok': 'ok' }); // should work
const foo2: Fn = () => { return Promise.resolve({ 'ok': 'ok' }) }; // should fail
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nGA7KBeKBvAsAKCvqAHgBUoIAPYCJAEwGcoAlCAYzgCcbC7h2BLJAHMANFACGSEAD4pACgCUALiikKVWgwAK7OAFs%20dCIQnSoAfihIIANwjsoy4gG5cAXxc5cbJDygAzBGV4RBR0BTQpKFkMKAByOABrWOV4pKhXeScoAHpsqDoACzgAVwAbGigAdw4ErzgfYH8EACYghGQ0KPkIzCh2CGBi9hRtPQMIADp%20ujhS22i4xOTFtIz0rNz8orKKvzE%20UqA)

Comment: I don't think you want a  generic function, since the implementation is deciding `T`. You could forbit any object type  that has a `then` member: https://tsplay.dev/WK9YZN Or you ca use a function to validate the function: https://tsplay.dev/WJ7gkw

Comment: Please see my edit, I'm actually looking by making `Fn` & `AsyncFn` incompatible. I not sure that's feasible.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir's approach does that for you, I think? https://tsplay.dev/wgAMMm

Comment: Yeah you're right, although I'm only partly satisfied. It references methods used by the type and not the type itself (Promise & Observable). That way you render object having these keys invalid.

Comment: It's the nature of TypeScript's type system, which is *structural* (based on the shapes of things) not *nominal* (based on the names/identities of things). You could try to find some other aspect of promise instances to test for, but `then` isn't completely unreasonable given the relationship of [*thenables*](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-7) to promises...

Comment: "If it looks like a duck, it's a duck. I don't care if it quacks or not."

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler you can create a higher order function, like [here](https://tsplay.dev/mL5eZW)